# Can I avoid page numbers in a report document with openright?

Tags: page-numbering

I have a report class and I dont want to switch it. If I use the openright option, I have the problem that empty pages are labled. Before taking the "openright" option out and inserting empty pages by hand I would like to know if it is possible to change the labelling of those empty pages.

Here is an example code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter One}
Some big text.
\chapter{End}
See you later aligator.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've just noticed that you haven't accepted (accepting and up-voting are two different actions) answers to your questions; please consider doing so; in case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`emptypage`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/emptypage) package:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter One}
Some big text.
\chapter{End}
See you later aligator.
\end{document}
```